# CaptivePortalLogin crashes every time I try to join a network

Tags: wi-fi, captive-portal

Every time I try to join an unencrypted wifi network that is protected by a web login (e.g. in a hotel), I get a popup message saying "Android System: Sign in to a Wi-Fi network ", I click on this message, and the result is:

```
CaptivePortalLogin has stopped
Open app again
```

I have tried also using Firefox or Chrome to find the portal by accessing a random HTTP page or the exact URL that my laptop is directed to to log in.  Firefox returns "Server not found"; Chrome says "You are offline", `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NO_INTERNET`.  My phone is set to not use mobile networks for data.

Is there any way to fix this or is there a workaround?

System information:

- Android 8.1.0 (security patch level 1 June 2018)
- Nokia 6.1, model TA-1050
- Kernel 4.4.78-perf+ (1/6/2018)

EDIT: I've tried a few apps as a workaround, such as [Wifi Web Auth](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=es.hol.galvisoft.wifiwebauth) in case CaptivePortalLogin is the problem.  This app errors with "Web page not available", `ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED`, which seems like an odd complaint for an app designed to establish a connection.  [Wifi Quick Login](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.albionresearch.wifiquickconnect) fails as well.

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve the issue but it sounds like CaptivePortalLogin may be corrupt.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the data of the _CaptivePortalLogin_ app? To help you out the exact reason for crash, you might need to get the crash report from the Logcat (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3643395/how-to-get-android-crash-logs)) and add it to your question.

Comment: I'm not certain, but would `chrome://interstitials/captiveportal?is_wifi=1` work?

Answer (score 0):

1. Turn off mobile data
2. Connect to WiFi
3. Go to this page: http://google.com/generate_204

Comment: That is the page CaptivePortalLogin calls upon, and it will show nothing (as the URL suggests, it just returns a 204 HTTP response). So why is it important to call specifically that page – what makes it better than the one Dennis suggested? To get to the captive portal, any URL will do. Further, how does this keep CaptivePortalLogin from crashing? Always having to turn off (and later on) mobile data manually is a work-around at best.

Comment: I can confirm that this works (or rather it's <https://www.gstatic.com/generate_204> that CaptivePortalLogin calls). @Izzy simply putting any URL does not work because the browser gives a no internet access error. Somehow, magically any.domain/generate_204 just works. Also, I've seen this behaviour only in stock Android devices. (For example, in MIUI, putting any URL works - I don't know why)

Answer (score 0):

My android was doing same thing. I just did a battery pull. That resolved the issue. Mine had been doing this for a few weeks.

Answer (score -2):

Enter Chrome and write http://192.168.0.1 or http://192.168.0.0. The authentication page should appear.

Comment: How does that keep the CaptivePortalLogin from crashing?

Comment: This should not always work. In most modern Captive Portals, the login URL is not the same as the local network gateway's address. This URL might just open the configuration page of the local router/gateway.